# Have trouble getting an input using Scanner Class

Tags: java

I'm going through my Java text book and for some reason I cannot compile the following code.

```
import java.util.*; 
public class ComputeAreaWConsoleInput
{

  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
   //Create Scanner Obj
   Scanner sc = New Scanner(System.in);

   //Get Radius
   System.out.print("Please Enter the Radius: ");
   double radius = sc.nextdouble();
   //determine area
   double area = 3.14159 * radius * radius;
   //display results
   System.out.println("The Area of the Circle w/ radius(" + radius +") is: " 
   + area);
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 /tmp/java_H98cOI/ComputeAreaWConsoleInput.java:8: error: ';' expected
   Scanner sc = New Scanner(System.in);
                   ^
1 error
```

What shall be done to compile the code?

Comment: `New Scanner() -> new Scanner`, ` sc.nextDouble() -> sc.nextDouble()`

Comment: I posted the working version as an answer buddy. Also added sc.close() =]

Comment: Java is case sensitive, `nextdouble` != `nextDouble`. Same about `new` and `New`.

Answer (score 1):

You've written:

```
New Scanner(System.in);
```

You `N` in `New` is capital.

The actual keyword is `new` and not `New`.

## Solution:

Change your line of code to:

```
new Scanner(System.in);
```

And there is another error.

It should be:

```
sc.nextDouble();  // with 'D' capital
```

and **not**

```
sc.nextdouble();
```

Comment: You have made another error. I have mentioned that too. Please accept the answer if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Two changes to your program.

Change New to new.Change the line

```
Scanner sc = New Scanner(System.in);
```

to

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

and other error in the program is scanning a double. Please change double to Double.So change the below line

```
double radius = sc.nextdouble();
```

to

```
double radius = sc.nextDouble();
```

It should work fine!

Answer (score 1):

See my comment: Here is the fixed version of your code:

```
public static void main (String [] 
{
//Create Scanner Obj
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

//Get Radius
System.out.print("Please Enter the Radius: ");
double radius = sc.nextDouble();
//determine area
double area = 3.14159 * radius * radius;
//display results
System.out.println("The Area of the Circle w/ radius(" + radius +") is: " + area);
sc.close();  // DO NOT forget this
}
```

Comment: Why do i need to close the scanner?

Comment: Check out [Scanner class API from oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: @Ziggy, this is why you must always close `Scanner` instance. Read about `close()` method. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close%28%29

Comment: from the same page **When a Scanner is closed, it will close its input source if the source implements the Closeable interface. ** .

Comment: If this worked for you, would you please accept my answer ?